# How to create a new library for ORACLE engine in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a new library for ORACLE engine in SAS, but exactly am not sure about the options to be entered in the text box. So, what am I supposed to do? (by user interface)

Here I am getting an invalid option name: in log window, when trying to create a new library, it  popups an error message i.e., `libname ORACLE is not assigned` (by user interface)

And so, I used PTF to make a connection to oracle here is the code...
but  ORACLE connection error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
```

I have a doubt about the path, can anyone please tell me the exact meaning of PATH in the code.

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle 
(user="scott" pw='tiger' path='D:\SAS COMPLETE PACKAGE\oracle');
create table studies as
select * from connection to oracle
(select * from emp);
 disconnect from oracle;
 quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path option needs to be a database name specified in your tnsnames.ora file. I do not think it is, based on the format. You should have something like

```
connect to oracle (user=scott pw=tiger path=CORP_DATA_WAREHOUSE_DEV)
```

or some such.

Please open your tnsnames.ora file in a text editor and see if the path you are trying to connect to is there. If it is not, please ask a colleague or dba to send you the tnsnames entry for what you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Hi YICK, can u please tell me how to use user interface to create a new library (by user interface), if any possibility please send me any screen shots regarding to it. here path means exactly where the Database has be installed or any thing else....